# FloatingActionButton library compile error

Tags: android

I added [FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton) dependency to my Gradle file, it was compiled successfully:

```
 compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
```

I added the following XML to my fragment layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_content_new"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/primary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary_pressed"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Now, at compile I get these errors:

```
Error:(17, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ic_action_content_new').
Error:(18, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'fab_colorNormal' with value '@color/primary').
Error:(19, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'fab_colorPressed' with value '@color/primary_pressed').
Error:(20, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'fab_colorRipple' with value '@color/ripple').
```

What should I set?

Comment: you don't really need that library anymore, FAB is included in support, now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FloatingActionButton was included in the Support Library.

So, I have to use [this approach](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) using the Design Support Library.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file add `xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`. This will fix the "No resource found that matches the given name..." errors.